# Cannot install ghc-mod due to “unattainable version of base”

Tags: windows, haskell, ghc

I'm trying to install the ghc-mod library on Windows. Using `stack install ghc-mod` shows this lengthy error message:

```
Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for ghc-mod-5.8.0.0:
    Cabal-2.4.1.0 from stack configuration does not match >=1.18 && <1.25  (latest matching version is 1.24.2.0)
    base-4.12.0.0 from stack configuration does not match >=4.6.0.1 && <4.10  (latest matching version is 4.9.1.0)
    cabal-helper must match <0.8 && >=0.7.3.0, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest matching
                 version is 0.7.3.0)
    djinn-ghc must match <0.1 && >=0.0.2.2, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest matching
              version is 0.0.2.3)
    extra-1.6.17 from stack configuration does not match <1.6 && >=1.4  (latest matching version is 1.5.3)
    ghc-8.6.5 from stack configuration does not match >=7.6 && <8.2
    ghc-syb-utils must match <0.3 && >=0.2.3, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest matching
                  version is 0.2.3.3)
    haskell-src-exts-1.20.3 from stack configuration does not match <1.20 && >=1.18  (latest matching version is 1.19.1)    hlint-2.1.11 from stack configuration does not match <2.1 && >=2.0.8  (latest matching version is 2.0.15)
    monad-journal-0.8.1 from stack configuration does not match <0.8 && >=0.4  (latest matching version is 0.7.2)
    optparse-applicative-0.14.3.0 from stack configuration does not match >=0.13.0.0 && <0.14  (latest matching version
                                  is 0.13.2.0)
    temporary-1.3 from stack configuration does not match <1.3 && >=1.2.0.3  (latest matching version is 1.2.1.1)
needed since ghc-mod is a build target.

Some different approaches to resolving this:

  * Build requires unattainable version of base. Since base is a part of GHC, you most likely need to use a different
    GHC version with the matching base.
```

Apparently, I need to change the version of ghc, but my version is higher than the one required, so updating doesn't help. Should I downgrade? How to do it without messing up the rest of my ghc ecosystem?

Using cabal to install it gives similar results.

Comment: In case it might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info): ghc-mod is somewhat old and deprecated (ref: https://github.com/DanielG/ghc-mod). Who / which tutorial told you to install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but you can't do this unless you are willing to downgrade to GHC 8.0. Note in the dependencies list it says `ghc (>=7.6 && <8.2)`. There is no GHC 8.1 (odd numbers are for testing), so its back to GHC 8.0.

Stackage provides a curated list of package versions which are known to compile together, along with a version of GHC. Each Long Term Support (LTS) is a specific set of these versions. As you can see from the list posted by Damián Rafael Lattenero that means going back to [LTS-9.21](https://www.stackage.org/lts-9.21).

The problem is that `ghc-mod` uses GHC as a library as well as a compiler, so it is very sensitive to the version, and you have to use the same version of the compiler for both `ghc-mod` and the software you are developing; having got a working version of `ghc-mod` you can't just switch to a later version of GHC for your own program.

Assuming you still want to do this, get [`stack` installed](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/). Then edit your `~/.stack/config.yaml` file (on Windows type `stack path --stack-root` to find where this is stored). Change it to say `resolver: lts-9.21`. Then say `stack install ghc-mod`.

Answer (score 0):

In [stackage](https://www.stackage.org/) you can find all the LTS versions and all the possible releases you can download:

[image]

and [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-mod) is the list of all the dependencies you need for ghc-mod:

[image]

You need to check that you don't have any outdated or unmatched.

Comment: I can't find the actual download links on that site. Could you guide me about what I should do exactly?